# Unlist in Python in order to use itertools.product

Tags: python, list, product

so I've been trying to do this for a while now, and I can't seem to find a solution.. Maybe you could help!
I'm trying to "unlist" a list of lists in order to use them in `itertools.product()`.
as you may know, `itertools.product()` can recieve multiple iterables. lets say I got this list of lists:

```
x=[[1,2,3],["a"],["B","C"]]
```

if we put this into the `itertools.product()`:

```
for i in product(x):
    print i
```

we will recieve

```
([1, 2, 3],)
(['a'],)
(['B', 'C'],)
```

What I need help with, is to find a way to "unlist" x, so there will be 3 iterables in the itertools.product(), as following:

```
for i in product([1,2,3],["a"],["B","C"]):
print i
```

which will print:

```
(1, 'a', 'B')
(1, 'a', 'C')
(2, 'a', 'B')
(2, 'a', 'C')
(3, 'a', 'B')
(3, 'a', 'C')
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply use the * operator (sometimes called "splat" operator) to unpack your argument:

```
list(product(*x))
Out[34]: 
[(1, 'a', 'B'),
 (1, 'a', 'C'),
 (2, 'a', 'B'),
 (2, 'a', 'C'),
 (3, 'a', 'B'),
 (3, 'a', 'C')]
```

Comment: out[34]? what does that mean?

Comment: @user3203956: You know how you usually see `>>>` at the start of each line when you're at the Python console?  The [IPython](http://ipython.org) interpreter defaults to distinguish input and output and give line numbers that way.

Answer (score 2):

[`itertools.product(*[[1, 2, 3], ["a"], ["B", "C"]])`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

Comment: Exactly this. The `*` operator returns a list of each element in a callable, exactly the same as `[item for item in iterable]`